# Problem with integrating reports using `<analytics:reportChart>` and `<apex:commandButton>`

Tags: javascript, reporting, analytics, reports-api, analytics-api

Did anyone run into this error before?

> Error while running $A.run() : Cannot read property 'join' of undefined' while using  to integrate and filter reports.

I have to render different reports on click of different buttons on a Visualforce page but the reports have filtering which I implemented using the `<analytics:reportChart>` filter attribute.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!pageNames}" var="each">
<apex:commandButton reRender="rightPane" action="{!renderReport}" value="{!each}" title="Report" status="progressIndicator">
    <apex:param name="q" value="{!each}" assignTo="{!pageName}" />
</apex:commandButton>
```

and 'page1' contains

```
<apex:pageBlock id="pbid">
<apex:actionFunction name="redirecttoReport" action="{!redirectRpt}" />
<analytics:reportChart reportId="{!reportId}" filter="{!newFilter}" size="large" cacheResults = "false"/>
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant code to show how you're using `<apex:actionFunction>` etc. ?

Comment: Hey.. I have corrected my code. Could you please check the above code.

Comment: Anyone have any idea about this issue ?